# Creating a Plot in R with Multiple Time Series Lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, linechart

I have a dataset that includes the following : years (from 2000 to 2020), incidence (number of incidence of a disease in each year) and location (30 locations, 29 for countries and 1 for global numbers).

Now, I want to create a multi time series plot in R using ggplot. I want the line for global numbers to be distinct from other countries, while other countries follow a rainbow color palette and have solid line types I want the line for global numbers to be black and dashed.

I wrote the following code but I cannot customize it further :

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=year, y=incidence) + 
  geom_line(aes(color=location)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data or some fake data best shared via `dput()`.

Answer (score 1):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to use custom color and linetype palettes which could be applied to your plot via `scale_xxx_manual`. To this end create named vectors of colors and linetypes which assign a color/linetype to each of your locations. Doing so makes it easy to set a specific color/linetype for the global location.

Using some fake example data based on the `gapminder` dataset:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(gapminder)

# Make example data
set.seed(123)

locs_select <- sample(unique(gapminder$country), 29)

df <- gapminder |>
  select(year,
    location = country,
    incidence = lifeExp
  )

df <- df |>
  summarise(
    location = "Global",
    incidence = mean(incidence), .by = year
  ) |>
  bind_rows(
    filter(df, location %in% locs_select)
  )
###

pal_color <- scales::hue_pal()(30)
pal_lty <- rep("solid", 30)
names(pal_color) <- names(pal_lty) <- sort(unique(df$location))
pal_color["Global"] <- "black"
pal_lty["Global"] <- "dashed"

ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = incidence)) +
  geom_line(aes(color = location, linetype = location)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = pal_color) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = pal_lty)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks! Great idea!